# Polymer two-way data binding and Facebook callback

Tags: polymer

I am very new to JavaScript and Polymer. I do like the PWA concept but now hit some roadblocks.

1. I tried to use polymerfire `<firebase-auth>` and was able to do google provider logins. But got blocked as I don't know how to do Facebook provider login and didn't find anywhere on how to use the tag as I wish to provide Facebook login too in JavaScript. If someone guides me to a source that works I will then not need part 2 of the question.
2. So, I tried facebook login via Graph API     `FB.login()`.     `FB.login()` has callback and I was not able to extract the response.name, public_profile and set it to Polymer attribute say     `{{user}}` like 
      `var userName = response.name; and then this.user = {displayName : userName};`

I noticed that as soon as I exit `FB.login()` callback on successful login, I lose the changes done in assignment in callback to 'this.user ' object.

My question is - I am not able to make two way binding work in polymer. How can I change the object in child element and then it propagates to all the pages / polymer elements?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I change the object in child element and then it propagates to all the pages / polymer elements?

Well really that depends on how you set up all the pages.  If you're in the parent, you can pass functions, variables, and objects to the child element by passing it in the component.

```
<ChildElement details={{_details}}/> // If you want to pass a details object to the child
<ChildElement sqft={{square(size)}}/> // This will call the square function inside your ChildElement and pass in the parameter size
```

Use the latter to call a function in your child and that function will have access to all the elements within that scope.

If you're in the child and you want to change something in the parent, you can do a callback with this.fire(someFunction()), and then create a function in your parent that with the same name.  It's not too bad when you're just passing from parent to child or vice versa but if you're passing it everywhere, then you might want to look into some sort of state management.  Passing things from one place to everywhere else will get ugly real fast.